# ghprbActualCommitAuthorMail returns wrong mail address

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using the GitHub pull request builder plugin in Jenkins to make pull requests on GitHub automatically trigger Jenkins jobs.

I am using GitHub Enterprise and when I try to get the values of environment vars `ghprbActualCommitAuthor` and `ghprbActualCommitAuthorMail`, I get incorrect values:

```
ghprbActualCommitAuthor : GitHub Enterprise
ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail : noreply@github.***.com
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is seen in GitHub Enterprise when users commit changes directly using the web UI or they have not set their email addresses.

According to GHE support:

> This is by design, since the commit is actually done by the GitHub Enterprise instance. This is because we do not impersonate users when creating commits.

You can fix this by ensuring that users make commits only through the Git clients using their own SSH credentials or Personal Access Tokens.

Comment: Hi Dibakar, Thanks for your answering, It's really helpful, now I am using git cmd window to push my code, and using github web ui to submit the PR, now I can get the correct value of ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail, Thanks!!!